# Blender (3.4.0.) Elbow Inverse Kinematics problem

Tags: modeling

There is a problem with IK of my character's elbow. Firstly should say that the whole armature and legs IK works pretty good. The problem is that when i add elbow pole target bone to the forearm IK constraint, elbow stops rotating as it should, it just stays straight (see screenshots). But when I delete elbow pole target it begin to turn properly as it should. Who knows what problem may be there? Thanks in advance.
[image]
[image]
I followed exactly this tutorial but hand IK didn't work : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hWfUe03Ib5E&t=690s&ab_channel=Kekdot

[image]

Comment: Hello please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Added link to the file

Answer (score 0):

You need to bend the elbow a bit in *Edit* mode otherwise Blender doesn't know how to bend the arm (same thing for the knees but it looks like they are already bent a bit):

[image]

Comment: Oh, i see, thank you very much for the help! :) Best Regards!